# Can I use `Semaphore.Release` as a readymade interlocked increment?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, multiprocessing, interlocked

I need a cross-process counter. I could map an integer in a memory-mapped file and use `Interlocked.Increment` on it, but it seems to me that `Semaphore.Release` would do the same thing and with less programming overhead. For example:

```
var mySem = new Semaphore(0, int.MaxValue, "mySemName");

// Get the next number.
int num = mySem.Release();
```

Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I don't think that's right. `Release` increments, and `WaitOne` decrements. I tested it just now in LINQPad.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes

But... You'd have to increment (or decrement it) in order to read it. There is no property to read the current number of slots (which makes sense because it's not really what they are for).

Comment: `Release` increments the counter returns the previous value.

Comment: @dan-gph that's my point. For it to be useful as a counter you probably need the ability to read it without modifying the value

Comment: Good point, but for my needs I only need to read the counter once at the time it is incremented.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure "rigmarole" is a technical term. With less overhead?  No.

Semaphores implement a special algorithm to ensure that the semaphore counter value is kept consistent over all threads.  The counter value must be locked before it is inspected, and the lock has to persist until the counter increment or decrement has been completed.  While it is locked, other threads may wait (if blocking) or simply fail (if non-blocking) and sometimes retry a moment later.

Interlocked increment merely ensures that the increment operation is atomic.  The interlocked increment of a byte does not require any special logic because bytewise increment is a CPU-level instruction.  Word and DWord increment may or may not be atomic depending on the chipset; if it is atomic, the framework will take advantage of that, and if it isn't, the framework will set up a lock to ensure that different threads don't increment different portions of memory within the same word or dword at the same time.

Almost all of the time, interlocked increment and decrement will have far less overhead.

Comment: I don't care about processor overhead here. I only care about programming overhead.

Comment: See, and I thought you only cared about rigmarole.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. I've changed it to "programming overhead".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, will work fine.  However this is not what the Semaphore class was designed to do.  Pity the poor guy that comes behind you to maintain the code.  He will be wondering where all the Semaphore.WaitOne() calls are.

Doing this same thing in shared memory is not hard.  Here is all you need...

```
            string mapname = "{EE9D59F3-18F7-4FB6-B76B-AC1E6902BD9B}";
            MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(mapname, sizeof(int));
            MemoryMappedViewAccessor mmva = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, sizeof(int));
            int count = Interlocked.Increment(ref *(int*)p.ToPointer());
```

But this is not code to be proud of either.  You would have to compile your code with /unsafe.

When there is no elegant approach, then you should revisit your design premise.  Why do you need a shared counter in the first place? If it is to make something unique, why not generate a GUID in each process?  If it is to aggregate a total, a more robust approach might be to post increments to a server.  If you really need high performance counting then perhaps C# is not the right vehicle for your ambitions.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find out how to do it without pinvoke. But I have gone with Semaphore.Release. I put a comment on the Release to explain what it does. Unfortunately I can't do anything about the design. I'm just trying to fix existing code. There is a client application and a web service. Both are multithreaded, however, the guy that wrote it didn't understand threads or their dangers. It is horrific. I am trying to fix a race condition where things are executing out of the desired order. To do that, I'm making the web service single threaded. Efficiency isn't a concern. ...

Comment: ... And to do that, I have made a "FIFO mutex" class. Unlike a regular mutex where Windows gets to decide who goes next, the waiting threads are queued up in FIFO order. I need the global counter to impose that order (like taking a number at a deli counter at a supermarket). It is still terrible, but it's the best I can do in the time I have.